# Django- NoReverseMatch at /posts/new/in/group-1/

Tags: django-urls

In my Forum like website. I wanted a feature wherein if a user is part of the group, only then user has an option to post in the group. Now, I am trying to pass the group slug in URL when "POST" button is clicked. But the URL doesn't match for some reason.There are two different apps for groups and posts respectively.

1. This is "group_detail.html" POST button is available to click once user has joined the group (line number 10)-

```
{% extends "groups/group_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>{{group.name}}</h1>
<h2> Member Count: {{group.members.count}}</h2>

  <div class="content">


                {% if user in group.members.all %}
                    <a href="{% url 'groups:leave' slug=group.slug %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-fill btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Leave</a>
    //line 10          <a href="{% url 'posts:create1' slug=group.slug %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-fill btn-warning" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>Post</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <a href="{% url 'groups:join' slug=group.slug %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-fill btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span> Join</a>
                {% endif %}

</div>
```

2. This is Post app's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='posts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", views.PostList.as_view(), name="all"),
    url(r"new/in/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$", views.CreatePost.as_view(), name="create1"),
    url(r"by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$",views.UserPosts.as_view(),name="for_user"),
    url(r"by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",views.PostDetail.as_view(),name="single"),
    url(r"delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",views.DeletePost.as_view(),name="delete"),
]
```

3. This is Post app's views.py

```
# from django.shortcuts import render

# # Create your views here.
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import Http404
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from groups.models import Group

from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin

from . import forms
from . import models

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    # form_class = forms.PostForm
    fields = ('message',)
    model = models.Post
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        group = get_object_or_404(Group,slug=self.kwargs.get("slug"))

        # try:
        #     GroupMember.objects.create(user=self.request.user,group=group)

        # except IntegrityError:
        #     messages.warning(self.request,("Warning, already a member of {}".format(group.name)))

        # else:
        #     messages.success(self.request,"You are now a member of the {} group.".format(group.name))

        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.group=group
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

4. This is post_form.html i.e form template

```
{% extends "posts/post_base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block content %}
<h4>Create New Post</h4>
//line 7 <form method="POST" action="{% url 'posts:create1' slug=group.slug %}" id="postForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I am getting following error when clicking on post button-
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWsnt.png)

Comment: ```'posts:create1'``` this is the name of the URL you are trying to reverse to but there is no URL named that in what you put here. I only see ```'create1', 'for_user', 'single', 'delete'```

Comment: I didn't get it Sir, doesn't ```posts:create1```  refer to the post application's url named 'create1' ? And i am referring to it in group_detail.html which is in groups app.

Comment: Try it without the ```posts:``` see if that works,

Comment: It didn't work, instead i wasn't even able to go to group_detail.html at the first place. I am not getting that for other cases with slug as keyword argument works but not this. Its the same syntax and it's not reaching the view because of mismatch of URL. It worked when i didn't have  group slug as keyword argument but in that case i won't be able to send group information to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was coming from post app's 'post_form.html' line 7 as commented.

change it from-

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'posts:create1' slug=group.slug %}" id="postForm">
```

to-

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="postForm">
```

I checked it by printing it on webpage, the group.slug becomes null in this form even if url shows the correct slug and hence nothing was printed at {{ group.slug }} in the webpage.

**This solves the above error.**

I also changed the post app's views.p for createPost view to make my feature work.
In this process, I changed "slug" to "pk" everywhere to refer the group with its primary key.

So now all the above files looks like following (The create post feature works [erfectl fine now) -

1. This is "group_detail.html" POST button is available to click once user has joined the group (line number 10)-

```
{% extends "groups/group_base.html" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>{{group.name}}</h1>
<h2> Member Count: {{group.members.count}}</h2>

  <div class="content">


                {% if user in group.members.all %}
                    <a href="{% url 'groups:leave' slug=group.slug %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-fill btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Leave</a>
   //line 10        <a href="{% url 'posts:create1' pk=group.pk %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-fill btn-warning" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span>Post</a></li>
                    {% else %}
                    <a href="{% url 'groups:join' slug=group.slug %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-fill btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle"></span> Join</a>
                {% endif %}

</div>
```

2. This is Post app's urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name='posts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r"^$", views.PostList.as_view(), name="all"),
    url(r"new/in/(?P<pk>\d+)/$", views.CreatePost.as_view(), name="create1"),
    url(r"by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$",views.UserPosts.as_view(),name="for_user"),
    url(r"by/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",views.PostDetail.as_view(),name="single"),
    url(r"delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$",views.DeletePost.as_view(),name="delete"),
]
```

3. This is post app's views.py-

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import Http404
from django.views import generic
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from groups.models import Group

from braces.views import SelectRelatedMixin

from . import forms
from . import models

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin, generic.CreateView):
    fields = ('message',)
    model = models.Post

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.group=get_object_or_404(Group,pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

4. This is post app's post_form.html i.e form template-

```
{% extends "posts/post_base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block content %}
<h4>Create New Post</h4>
//line 7  <form method="POST" action="" id="postForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```